# JUnit Cucumber cannot find steps

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

During the execution of the "mvn test" command, I obtain this error message :

```
7 Scenarios (7 undefined)
31 Steps (31 undefined)
0m0,000s

You can implement missing steps with the snippets below...
```

Nevertheless all this steps is defined well in my files and correspond well to snippets proposed in the error message !

This is my Cucumber runner :

```
@RunWith(ExtendedCucumber.class)

@ExtendedCucumberOptions(jsonReport = "target/cucumber.json", retryCount = 3, detailedReport = true, detailedAggregatedReport = true, overviewReport = true, jsonUsageReport = "target/cucumber-usage.json", usageReport = true, toPDF = true, outputFolder = "target")

@CucumberOptions(plugin = { "html:target/cucumber-html-report", "json:target/cucumber.json", "pretty:target/cucumber-pretty.txt",
    "usage:target/cucumber-usage.json", "junit:target/cucumber-results.xml" }, features = { "src/test/resources" }, glue = { "src/test/java" })

public class CucumberTest {}
```

I have multiple feature files and multiple step definitions files.

My dependencies :

```
<properties>
    <cucumber.version>1.2.5</cucumber.version>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-runner</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                        <version>2.20</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Any ideas ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is it possible that you have old sources/resources inside of `target/` directory? I'd try to run it as `mvn clean test` to ensure that you're using the newest versions of the code.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I already executed mvn clean test several times without success  - i have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

The value for `glue = { "src/test/java" }` must be the package name, instead of the path name.

If your step definition classes are in the package `steps` (so they are stored in the path `src/test/java/steps`) the value must be `glue = { "steps" }`.

Comment: No luck even after defining glue value as step Definition package. Any other suggestion, please ?

Comment: @GSN Hard to suggest anything without knowing what you tried and what's the actual error. You might consider to create a new question containing a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).